# subdomain to url redirect with mod_rewrite and htaccess?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a mod rewrite that currently redirects

> domain.com/folder/user

to

> domain.com/folder.php?username=user

using:

> RewriteRule ^folder/(.+)$ folder.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]

What I need done however is redirect http://user.domain.com/ to http://www.domain.com/folder.php?username=user . And if possible, I could exclude certain subdomains (like www. mail., etc. from being forwarded).

How would I do this? Any help is GREATLY appreciated :)

Comment: How are virtual servers configured on your host?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but I use Apache and they're set in httpd.conf ...I have root level access though if that helps.

Comment: You find an answer below that shows you how to manage that as long as all domains point into the same area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How it works:

- Extract `user` from `http://user.domain.com/` and save a backreference to it with a [`RewriteCondition`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).
- The hostname of the request is stored in a **Server-Variable**.

  > [image]
  >   Figure : The back-reference flow through a rule.
  >   In this example, a request for `/test/1234` would be transformed into `/admin.foo?page=test&id=1234&host=admin.example.com`. [Source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- In the [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) use the `RewriteCondition`'s backreference.
- See also the note in the `RewriteRule` section:

  > If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.
- Configure your (virtual) server to listen to all the domains you want to-rewrite within to ensure all requests are passed into the same section/root of your server where you can do the rewrite. Otherwise you need to proxy internally.